# Why does this c++ example not compile on MSVC?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015

## Example

Why does the following snippet not build on MSVC (2015, 64 bit). It is a boiled down version of other code, that is why it looks a bit strange.

```
#include <string>

template<class T>
class A {};

template<class T>
using AA = A<T>;

//duplicate using statement
template<class T>
using AA = A<T>;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

## Compile errors

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(780): error C2665: 'std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<_Elem,_Alloc>>::_String_alloc': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
>           with
>           [
>               _Elem=char,
>               _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
>           ]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(744): note: could be 'std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<_Elem,_Alloc>>::_String_alloc(std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<_Elem,_Alloc>> &&)'
>           with
>           [
>               _Elem=char,
>               _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
>           ]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(744): note: or       'std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<_Elem,_Alloc>>::_String_alloc(const std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<_Elem,_Alloc>> &)'
>           with
>           [
>               _Elem=char,
>               _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
>           ]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(587): note: or       'std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<_Elem,_Alloc>>::_String_alloc(void)'
>           with
>           [
>               _Elem=char,
>               _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
>           ]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(780): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char>>)'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\xstring(775): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\system_error(522): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &)' being compiled
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdexcept(21): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' being compiled

## Conditions

There is no error if

- **built on linux or mac with gcc**
- `#include <string>` is removed
- duplicate using statement is removed

## Building

Built by doing `cl main.cpp` on Windows 8.1 with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24210 for x64.

Comment: Looks like a VC bug to me.

Comment: This looks like the most bizarre bug ever... +1

Comment: If you want to see something even weirder, move the `#include` to the end!

Comment: It shows different errors on http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual (19.00.23506 (x64)), but compiles successfully on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ (19.10.24903.0 (x86)). It might be fixed already, or it might be an x64-only problem, or it might depend on more details than merely the compiler version.

Comment: @hvd: I get the same problem on 32-bit. Might be just fixed already.

Comment: I opened a bug report with microsoft here: [3119195](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3119195)